# How would I find the equation of f(x) in terms of x and y?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

The function $f(x)$ was rotated along the x-axis to form a surface.
$$  \int_{-4}^{4} \int_{y=-\sqrt{16-x^{2}}}^{y=\sqrt{16-x^{2}}} \int_{-f(x)}^{f(x)} dzdydx$$
This is what i thought it would be however, I am not sure what I should be integrating... I have my limits for my integrals however, I do not have the equation of this cylinder to integrate into (which I think I need). If anyone can either fix my integration (if it is wrong) or/and provide me with the equation of a cylinder that would be great.  Or if someone can find my f(x) as f(x,y).

Comment: Are you finding surface area or the volume?

Comment: The volume of the intersection of both of the surfaces.

Comment: You need to edit the question then. Right now that is not how it reads.

Comment: I hope that fixed it

Comment: Yes it's better. The integral given by Matthew Pilling is correct if you want to find volume inside green cylinder.

Comment: I would say, numerically. One simple way is Monte Carlo. Choose a rectilinear volume which contains the intersection. Then generate random <x, y, z> pairs in this volume and check whether each one lies in the intersection.  Do this a large number of times and then divide the number of in-intersection points by the total number of points: this gives you the fraction of the bounding volume occupied by the intersected solid. Since you know the volume of the bounding volume, using this fraction you can calculate the approximate volume of the intersection.

Answer (score 4):

lets put $r = f(x)$

When we rotate the the function around the x axis, the magnitude of the function will be the radius of the rotated body.

$y = r\cos t\\
z = r\sin t\\
t = \arccos \frac {y}{r}\\
z = r\sin(\arccos \frac {y}{r}) = r \sqrt {1 - (\frac yr)^2} = \sqrt{f^2(x) - y^2}$

$dS = (-\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}, 1)\\$

$(-\frac {f(x)f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)^2 - y^2}}, \frac {y}{\sqrt{f^2(x)-y^2}}, 1)\\
\|dS\| = \sqrt {\frac {f^2(x)f'^2(x) + y^2 + f^2(x) - y^2}{f^2(x) - y^2}}\\
\sqrt {\frac {f^2(x)(f'^2(x)+1)}{f^2(x) - y^2}}$

The surface of inside the cylinder:

$\int_{-4}^4 \int_{-\sqrt{16-x^2}}^\sqrt{16 - x^2} f(x)\sqrt {\frac {f'^2(x) + 1}{f^2(x) + y^2}} \ dy\ dx$

And that would be one of the surfaces... there would also be a surface where $z$ is negative, doubling the result, if you want both.

Update... the work above gives the surface area...

If you want the volume.

$\int_{-4}^4 \int_{-\sqrt{16-x^2}}^\sqrt{16 - x^2}\int_{-\sqrt{f^2(x) - y^2}}^{\sqrt {f^2(x) - y^2}} dz\ dy\ dx$

Comment: Ok that looks insane... I do not fully comprehend it. Just to clarify, this would give me the volume of intersection between the surface and cylinder, where z is positive so I would need to double it to get the full volume?

Comment: @AlexGola are you looking for the *volume* or the *surface area*?

Comment: I am looking for the volume

Comment: You are finding the volume of the region of space *inside* the blue surface and *outside* the green surface. Am I correct? FYI this response is calculating surface area, not volume.

Comment: oh my fault. Yes I want to find the volume of the space where the blue and green surface intersect. Essentially, find the volume that they share (kinda, I am sorry, I dont really know how to phrase it).

Comment: So we're definitely inside the green cylinder... right? And we want to cap this region by the blue surface?

Comment: I think the volume you seek is $$\int_{-4}^4 \int_{-\sqrt{16-x^2}}^{\sqrt{16-x^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{(f(x))^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{(f(x))^2-y^2}}\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$$ but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes the volume I am looking for is definitely in inside the green cylinder. I can see how u arrived at that answer, I will see if it lines up with my other values. Thank you

Comment: Just a useful remark. The equation of the surface generated by rotating $y=f(x)$ around the $x-$axis is $\sqrt{y^2+z^2}=(f(x))^2$. If we rotated around the $y$-axis, this would instead be $y=f\Big(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\Big)$

Comment: Yea thanks, I am just wondering what would the integrand be in this case? Because I had a similar issue with my triple integral where I did not know what the integrand was.

Comment: @AlexGola But I wonder how you came across this question if you are in high school. This is quite a bit of cumbersome integral for high school.

Comment: This work gives the surface area.

Comment: I am going a little above school expectations for my project. @MathLover

Comment: @AlexGola ok but even if you convert it into polar coordinates, to me it still seems a very difficult integral to evaluate. So you are not going a little above expectation but a lot :) may be I am wrong

Comment: This is worth a chunk of my final grade, I going to try my best. As of right now, I am still a little lost as to how to solve it. But I will try my best. @MathLover

Comment: @AlexGola good luck. The integral set up itself is not that difficult. So I would say if you need ideas on how to solve it, you should post a question giving the context, stating what you had done so far and that you were looking for suggestions on how best to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Given your function $f(x)$, the equation of (half) the surface is
$$
z(x,y)=\sqrt{f(x)^2-y^2}
$$
because for any point of the surface the distance from the $x$ axis is $f(x)$.
So the volume over the region $x^2+y^2\le 16$ is
$$
\int_{-4}^4\int_{-\sqrt{16-x^2}}^{\sqrt{16-x^2}} z(x,y)dy dx
$$

Comment: Ok took me a while to understand this but isnt the integral supposed to be dydx not dxdy?

Comment: Yes sorry :). edit the typo